# Jetpack Compose bottom navigation: switch to another tab still triggers composition of original tab content when viewmodel is passed

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

While navigating from bottom nav bar from tab A to tab B, it is understandable that content for tab B is recomposed, but why the tab A is also recomposed? It should only be recomposed when the user navigates back to A.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var accountManager: AccountManager
    private val productViewModel: ProductViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AndroidTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Content(productViewModel = productViewModel, accountManager = accountManager)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Content(productViewModel: ProductViewModel, accountManager: AccountManager) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val items = listOf(Screen.Home, Screen.Account)

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            BottomNavigation(
                backgroundColor = colorScheme.primary
            ) {
                val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
                val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination
                items.forEach { screen ->
                    val selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == screen.route } == true
                    BottomNavigationItem(
                        label = { androidx.compose.material.Text(text = stringResource(id = screen.resourceId)) },
                        selected = selected,
                        selectedContentColor = Color.White,
                        unselectedContentColor = Color.LightGray,
                        icon = {
                            Icon(
                                if (selected) screen.selectedIcon else screen.unselectedIcon,
                                contentDescription = null
                            )
                        },
                        onClick = {
                            navController.navigate(screen.route) {
                                popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                                    saveState = true
                                }
                                launchSingleTop = true
                                restoreState = true
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = Screen.Home.route,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            composable(Screen.Home.route) {
                ContentScreen(productViewModel = productViewModel) <-- called when navigating to Account route !!!
            }
            composable(Screen.Account.route) {
                AccountScreen(accountManager = accountManager)
            }
        }
    }
}

@HiltViewModel
class ProductViewModel @Inject constructor(private val productRepository: ProductRepository): ViewModel() {
    private var _modules = MutableStateFlow<List<ProductResponse.Result.Module>>(emptyList())
    val modules = _modules.asStateFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch { getModules() }
    }

    suspend fun getModules() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val modules = productRepository.getModules()
            _modules.emit(modules)
        }
    }
}
```

Why passing a ViewModel to ContentScreen() is trigger recomposition unnecessarily? If I do not pass the ViewModel then it does not recompose. Though there suggestions that viewmodel can he hoisted up but I think it should still be ok to pass the ViewModel to composable down.